# variables table in D8?

Tags: 8, configuration

What database table in Drupal 8 replaces `variables` table in Drupal 7?

Where are the values of Configuration stored?

example : `$config->set('message', 'Hi')->save();`
Where can I find value of `message` variable in database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you can find the equivalent in the `config` table.

```
mysql> desc config;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| collection | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| data       | longblob     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from config where name = 'system.theme';
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| collection | name         | data                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            | system.theme | a:3:{s:5:"admin";s:5:"seven";s:7:"default";s:6:"bartik";s:5:"_core";a:1:{s:19:"default_config_hash";s:43:"gOjer9hADYYnbCJVZMFZIIM1azTFWyg84ZkFDHfAbTz";}} |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

> By default, the "active" configuration is stored in the database
>   ("config" table). This is for performance and security reasons. This
>   is the complete configuration for the entire site at that moment.
>   Configuration can be exported and imported as YAML files, either in
>   it's entirety, or a single piece of configuration, using Drush config
>   commands or the Configuration Manager.

More info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration

Comment: I think that's only half of the story - there's now the state API, which is used for instance-specific config. The last time cron ran would be in state rather than config, for example, whereas it was all lumped into Variables in D7

Comment: @Clive, can you please add more explanation to this as another answer? or else pls provide a link for reference.. Thanks :)